# File to import not found or unreadable: normalize-rails/normalize. Administrate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I am using the Administrate gem and noticed there was a dependency issue, which required the gem `sass-rails` [thoughtbot/administrate #134](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/issues/134). I have the gem already installed and `Gemfile.lock` has `sass-rails (5.0.1)`. The error highlights the `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` tag in the `application.html.erb`. I cannot find anything further to this issue, could anybody shed some light on how to resolve?

Comment: What is the error message, specifically?

Comment: `Sass::SyntaxError in Home#index. File to import not found or unreadable: normalize-rails/normalize."